# SQL - Return a default value when my search returns no results along with search criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I am searching with a query 
    --Code Format

```
SELECT COLA,COLB,COLC from MYTABLE where SWITCH IN (1,2,3);
```

If `MYTABLE` does not contain rows with `SWITCH` 1,2 or 3 I need default values returned along with the `SWITCH` value. How do I do it?

Below is my table format

```
COLA | COLB | COLC | SWITCH
------------------------------
A       B      C        1
a       b      c        2
```

i want a query when I search with

```
select * from MYTABLE where switch in (1,2,3)
```

That gets results like this --

```
COLA | COLB | COLC | SWITCH
------------------------------
A       B      C        1
a       b      c        2
NA      NA     NA       3
```

Comment: How do you want the default values and the result set to look like if there are no values with the criteria?

Comment: Essentially Im trying to figure out for which values of SWITCH i dont have rows in my table. In case if you're trying to help..

Comment: Maybe you should consider posting a sample table, sample data and desired output. You have several people guessing but it isn't clear what you want here. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 3):

```
--Check to see if any row exists matching your conditions
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT COLA,COLB,COLC from MYTABLE where SWITCH IN (1,2,3))
     BEGIN
         --Select your default values
     END
ELSE
     BEGIN
        --Found rows, return them
        SELECT COLA,COLB,COLC from MYTABLE where SWITCH IN (1,2,3)
     END
```

Comment: If I have a row with switch =1, this query returns result for switch =1 and I do not see any records for switch=2 or 3 ; Basically i want to know for which values of switch I do not have records in my table

Comment: @Sudha then I think it is something with your query, not what I posted, this just evaluates if any records exist for your given query, if not, then do a select for returning your default, else it does the select statement you provided.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
SELECT COLA,COLB,COLC from MYTABLE where SWITCH IN (1,2,3)
union select 5555, 6666, 7777 where not exists (
  SELECT COLA,COLB,COLC from MYTABLE where SWITCH IN (1,2,3)
);
```

`5555`, `6666`, `7777` being the default row in case there aren't any rows matching your criteria.

Comment: This answer is for situation when my SWITCH value is outside 1, 2 or 3. I need a solution for when my table does not have a row with  SWITCH value 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: Second try. Like it now?

Answer (score 2):

if not exists( SELECT 1 from MYTABLE where SWITCH IN (1,2,3))
select ***default_value***

Comment: So my table has 4 columns as in the sql above. If I have a record for switch =1, i want results returned; If I do not have a record with switch = 2, I want something like 'Not available' returned. This sql doesnt work for me

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to tackle this. You need a table of the SWITCH values you want to look at. Then a simple left join makes this super easy.

```
select ColA
    , ColB
    , ColC
    v.Switch
from
(
    values
    (1)
    , (2)
    , (3)
)v (Switch)
left join YourTable yt on yt.Switch = v.Switch
```

Answer (score 2):

You can Use a Split Function And Left Join As Shown Below:

```
Select ISNULL(ColA,'NA') As ColA,ISNULL(ColB,'NA') As ColB,ISNULL(ColC,'NA') As ColC,ISNULL(Switch,a.splitdata) 
from [dbo].[fnSplitString]('1,2,3',',') a
LEFT JOIN #MYTABLE t on a.splitdata=t.Switch
```

**[dbo].[fnSplitString]** is a Split Function with 2 arguments - Delimeter Separated String and Delimeter and Output a Table.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
Given the new explanation, I changed the answer completely. I think I got your question now:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE AS mt
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 1 AS s UNION SELECT 2 AS s UNION SELECT 3 AS s) AS st
ON st.s = mt.SWITCH
```

You could change the `SELECT 1 AS s UNION SELECT 2 AS s UNION SELECT 3 AS s`part to a subquery that results in all possible values `SWITCH` could assume. E.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SWITCH FROM another_table_with_all_switches
```

If all want is the value of switch that is not in `MYTABLE`, not the whole table with null values, you could try:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 1 AS s UNION SELECT 2 AS s UNION SELECT 3) AS st
WHERE st.s NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT SWITCH FROM MYTABLE)
```

Comment: This returns all the results in the table :(

Comment: From what I understood, you wanted all registers that are 1,2 or 3, and a default value to all the others, right? If not, could you elaborate a little bit more? Like give an example input and output desired

Comment: @Sudha I think I got your question now, see if the edit helps